# Regex matching in Python involving multiple patterns

Tags: python, regex

I have a few tricky regex matches I am using **re** package in Python.

**Case 1:**

List of entries containing *Names* & *Age* like

```
John (45)
Mike (37)
```

The pattern I want to search is Name (some number) and copy all those lines with the matching set of names. If I use a syntax like ...

```
found = re.search(r"(Name1|Name2|Name3) (\d+)", line)
if found: valid_line.append(line)
```

There are some issues. What corrections are needed here?

Comment: _There are some issues_ - and those are?

Answer (score 0):

Using `re.search`

**Ex:**

```
import re
s = """John (45)
Mike (37)"""

for line in s.split("\n"):
    if re.search("\w+\s+\(\d+\)", line):
        print(line )
```

*Or:*

```
for line in s.split("\n"):
    if re.search("(John|Mike)\s+\(\d+\)", line):
        print(line )
```

**Output:**

```
John (45)
Mike (37)
```

- You need to escape the brackets `\(\)`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it'd be a bonus for you to get the name and age. I'm not very good at regex so I'm sure there's a more concise method.

> `([a-zA-Z]+)\s+\(([^)]\d)\)`

#### Example

```
import re

line = "John (45) Mike (37) John (45) Mike (37)"
exp = r"([a-zA-Z]+)\s+\(([^)]\d)\)"

for (name, age) in re.findall( exp, line ):
    print(name, "is", age, "years old.")
```

#### Output

```
John is 45 years old.
Mike is 37 years old.
John is 45 years old.
Mike is 37 years old.
```